# Looping through a linked list containing arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, linked-list, nested-loops

i'm struggling to work out how to use a loop to run through a list which contains 4 array values being "a_value", "b_value", "c_value", "d_value". Each of my arrays in this list have 23 elements. the outcome im looking for is for a loop to run though the list adding all 23 elements of each array. E.G. total of "a_value" then total of "b_value" and so on. this is what i have so far.
Thank you guys.

```
class node():
    def __init__(self, dataval = None):
        self.dataval = dataval
        self.nextval = None

class linked_list():
    def __init__(self):
        self.headval = None

    def listprint(self):
        printval = self.headval
        while printval != None:
            print (printval.dataval)
            printval = printval.nextval        


arraylist = linked_list()
arraylist.headval = node(a_value) # each '""_value' has 23 integer values 
in them
e2 = node(b_value)
e3 = node(c_value)
e4 = node(d_value) 

arraylist.headval.nextval = e2
e2.nextval = e3
e3.nextval = e4

arraylist.listprint()

i = 1
x = 1
total_a = 0
total_b = 0
total_c = 0
total_d = 0

for n in arraylist:
    for z in range(len(n)-1)
        value_a = int(a_value[i])
        total_a+=value_a
        i+= 1
    x+=1
```

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: Did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
    a_value = [1,2,3]
    b_value = [4,5,6]
    c_value = [7,8,9]
    d_value = [10,11,12]

    class node():
        def __init__(self, dataval = None):
            self.dataval = dataval
            self.nextval = None


    class linked_list():
        def __init__(self):
            self.headval = None

        def listprint(self):
            printval = self.headval
            while printval != None:
                print (printval.dataval)
                printval = printval.nextval


    arraylist = linked_list()
    arraylist.headval = node(a_value)
    e2 = node(b_value)
    e3 = node(c_value)
    e4 = node(d_value)

    arraylist.headval.nextval = e2
    e2.nextval = e3
    e3.nextval = e4

    node = arraylist.headval     # fetch head node  
    nextval = node.nextval         # fetch next to node
    list = []
    list.append(node.dataval)       # enter all head list

    while nextval:              # this loop will break as nextval is none
        node = node.nextval     # node now becomes next and repeat
            if hasattr(node, 'nextval'):
                nextval = node.nextval
            else:
                nextval = None
        list.append(node.dataval)

    sum = 0

    for x in list:          # sum in the end or break into 23 for all separate
        for y in x:
            sum+=y

    print(list, sum)

    #OUTPUT [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]] 78
```

Works fine :)

Comment: (nextval = node.nextval) is getting error " 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'nextval' "

Comment: Just add a check before fetching the value.

Comment: what kind of check would you use?

Comment: great! thank you buddy! just one last thing as im curious, is there a way to get it so it would print "[[6],[15],[24],[33]]" instead Thanks :)

Comment: You have to play around that :D learn guy and accept answer if it helped you :p